# php で nginx の アクセスログからリファラ、IPの情報を取得したい

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

### 環境

- Ubuntu
- nginx
- php5-fpm

アクセスログ 
`/var/log/nginx/hoge.com.access.log`

### 目的

hoge.com に他のサイトからきたアクセスの中身でリファラとIPを定期的に crontab を利用して取得したい。 
想像で、crontab を使うと思っていますがそれ以外の定期実行の方法がありましたら、ご教授ください。

monitor.hoge.com という監視ページを作成して、そこに php でアクセスログの情報を整理して表示したいです。

`file_get_contents` を利用して取得したい。 
取得する先のログファイルは 
`/var/log/nginx/hoge.com.access.log`
です。

整理しますと
php ファイルを作成し、 `file_get_contents` を利用して `/var/log/nginx/hoge.com.access.log` から IPとリファラを抽出してデータベースに INSERT する。
その後、管理画面に php で情報を表示する。

です。

ご回答お待ちしております。

Comment: 環境、目的、実装案はわかりましたが、それで今回はどのようなご質問でしょうか。なにについての回答をお求めですか？

Answer (score 1):

定期実行ではありませんが fluentd を使ってアクセスログの出力をトリガーにDB格納を行えば、管理画面の php は DBを読み込んで情報を表示するだけで済みそうな気がします。

「Nginx fluentd DBの名前」でググれば詳しくわかると思います。